# System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.CreateTextResponse error

Tags: json, wcf, jsonp

its complining on CreateTextResponse i am using VS2010 target framework is 3.5
error:

*'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext' does not contain a definition for 'CreateTextResponse' and no extension method 'CreateTextResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
[OperationContract] 
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "GET",  
    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
public Message Blah() 
{ 
    var j = new { Name = "blah1", Data = "blah2" }; 

    JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
    string jsonClient = s.Serialize(j); 

    return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse("method(" + jsonClient + ");", 
        "application/json; charset=utf-8", Encoding.UTF8); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from the documentation of the [CreateTextResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989566.aspx) method:

> Supported in: 4

This basically means that this method has been introduced in .NET 4.0. No need to look for it if you are targeting .NET 3.5. Guess it's time to upgrade :-)

Comment: Here's an alternative: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898(VS.90).aspx.

Comment: can you exlain me or can i just use response.write method?

Comment: Download the sample application and use the included classes to generated JSONP response.

Comment: i have downloaded and look into it but did not get how to use, is there any blog out there that explains? ms help really makes me confuse.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219937/testing-building-msdn-article-json-with-padding-ajax/4220102#4220102