# Testing/Building MSDN article "JSON with Padding (AJAX) "

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

UPDATE 3

```
var local = 'http://localhost:1163/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=?';
            var dev = 'http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomer?method=?';
            $.getJSON(dev, function (customer) {    
                alert(customer.Address);
                alert(customer.Name);
            });
```

if i run `http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=foo'` on the remote domain i get **access denied error** AND if i run `http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=?'` i get this error(see below) and i have exactly what you have in your sample page. it seems that "method=foo" "get access denied" and "method=?" throw this error: URI:

```
"http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc.svc/GetCustomer?method=jsonp1290197214042"
```

**UPDATE3**

**UPDATE2**

i have tested with two different scenario:

1) **works fine with localhost**

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:1163/service.svc/getcustomer?method=?', function (customer) {
                alert(customer.Address);
                alert(customer.Name); 
            });
```

2) **does not work with cross domain**

```
 $.getJSON('http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=?', function (customer) {

                alert(customer.Address);
                alert(customer.Name); 
            });
```

i get this error:

Message: Expected ';'
Line: 1
Char: 11
Code: 0

```
URI: http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomer?method=jsonp1290183992345
```

**UPDATE2**

**UPDATE1**

when i run the service in the browser
http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer
i get the the popup window asking for me to fine or save the file, so i save the file to browser and i open it in the notepad and i see that the data so its returning me the jsonp.

```
{"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"}
```

where exactly you want me to put return false in the button?

on the debugger i put just for steping in the code.

**UPDATE1**

**UPDATE:**
below is how i am calling to my cross domain service.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#driver").click(function (event) {

            $.getJSON('http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=?', function (customer) {
            debugger
                alert(customer.Address);
                alert(customer.Name); 
            });
        });
    });
```

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 19 Nov 2010 14:56:22 UTC

```
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 1
Char: 11
Code: 0
URI: 'http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/GetCustomer?method=JsonPCallBack
```

i get the above error:

**Update end**

I've been learning and building JSONP Web services using WCF on fx3.5. I finally got a sample togather with the help of this [article](http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/) and MSDN article JSON with Padding (AJAX)

i am running the service on my local

```
http://localhost:4058/WiringJsonImpl.svc
```

to test it out.

instead of getting the standard wsdl screen it display the message "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled"

i paste the address in the url

```
 http://yourserver.com/LocationService.svc/GetLocation?method=jsonpCallback
```

and hit enter i see the blank screen with this message in IE browser.

```
The webpage cannot be found 
 HTTP 400
```

in my web.conig i see the error but does not stop running the application:

```
 <bindings>
   <customBinding>
    <binding name="jsonpBinding">
     <jsonpMessageEncoding/> //<<<error here
     <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
    </binding>
   </customBinding>
  </bindings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the provided sample application (JSONP) the service method is called `GetCustomer` and not `GetLocation`. So to call it:

```
http://localhost:1163/service.svc/getcustomer?method=jsoncallback
```

which returned the following response in my browser:

```
jsoncallback( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"} );
```

The reason that Visual Studio Intellisense underlines the `<jsonpMessageEncoding/>` is because this is a custom binding element and not part of the schema and it is not known. You can safely ignore this warning.

The only problem with this sample is that the files are packaged in a Class Library instead of Web Application. In order to run the service more easily in the Visual Studio built in server you could create a new Web Application, copy all the files to this new application and run it. You just need to modify this line in web.config:

```
<add name="jsonpMessageEncoding"
     type="Microsoft.Ajax.Samples.JsonpBindingExtension, service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                                                            ^
```

to include your web application name:

```
<add name="jsonpMessageEncoding"
     type="Microsoft.Ajax.Samples.JsonpBindingExtension, MyWebAppName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
                                                              ^
```

That's all. Now go ahead and write a client application which consumes this JSONP stream. jquery does a great job with the [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:1163/service.svc/getcustomer?method=?', function(customer) {
    alert(customer.Address); 
});
```

I have uploaded my [working version here](http://jump.fm/DXUES).

Comment: Thanks Darin, as i mentioned above that i was following the article (not the msdn) sample code... i will try and get back to you

Comment: @Chicagoland, sorry I thought you was trying to run the MSDN sample. Haven't read the article yet, but the sample works fine.

Comment: @chicagoland, sure see my updated post, I have included an example using the `$.getJSON` method but of course the first step is to make the web service output the correct JSONP response.

Comment: i try to download the project which you uploaded but dont see that there is a download link?... i thought i have to wait for few minutes to showedup but still dont see anything.

Comment: @Chicagoland, yes sorry it's at the bottom on the right side. It says: `Save file to your PC: click here`, no need to wait, you just need to find it as it is small font. Sorry about the crappy site :-)

Comment: i click on it but does not do anything, it just stay on the same page... how about upload to mediafire? thanks for your help

Comment: thanks i  able to download :), the purpose this msdn sample is to work for "cross domain" correct? and i will try that tomorrow and update you.

Comment: Yes absolutely, JSONP is meant to be able to call the service from a client script cross domain. If your client is another .NET application then standard WCF is just fine. JSONP is really meant from javascript clients.

Comment: @Darin, sorry for asking you so many questions but looks like you are the expert so please bare with me, what is the technique for posting the data from client to server?

Comment: @Chicagoland, if you want to send a POST verb from javascript cross domain then this is simply impossible. The way JSONP works is by inclusion of a `<script>` tag in the DOM which can only send a GET request.

Comment: so there is no other way to send the data from client to server ?

Comment: Sure there is: use `$.getJSON` as I showed in my answer. Behind the scenes this sends a GET request to the server.

Comment: @Darin: i am bit confused now, you mentioned that you can NOT send a post verb from js cross domain... thanks for being patience with me. can you please show me how you will send data from client to server.

Comment: @Chicagoland, POST and GET are two different HTTP verbs (I suggest you reading about how HTTP protocol works). When sending an AJAX request you could specify the verb you would like to use. The thing is that when doing a cross domain AJAX request you can only use GET. And the way to do this with jQuery is using the $.getJSON method as shown in my answer. So all you have to do is use this method. That's all. Just put the $.getJSON call I showed in my answer into your html page and it should successfully call your web service (assuming of course the URL is correct and the service is running).

Comment: Darin, i understand about post and get verbs but when it comes to cross domain i get little bit confused and some says you can not pass the data and some says you can so i just wanted to make sure that before i do that exercise. i have tested the sample you have showed and its working find but now i have to figured out how to pass the data from client to server will you help me or show me how you will pass some data from client to server (service) ?

Comment: If we suppose that your service method takes the `id` parameter you can pass it like this: `$.getJSON('http://localhost:1163/service.svc/getcustomer?method=?', { id: '123' },  function(customer) { alert(customer.Address); });`. Notice the second argument of the $.getJSON method.

Comment: Darin: i just started testing using the code from cross domain and i get the error and i have updated my question, please have a look at it.

Comment: @Chicagoland, what does the `#driver` selector corresponds to? You might need to `return false` in your `click` handler if this is an anchor or submit button to cancel the default action. Also what is this `debugger` keyword before your alerts? Also have you verified that your web service returns proper JSONP: `jsoncallback( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"} );` when calling it directly in your browser address bar?

Comment: What you've shown in your latest update is JSON and not JSONP. What if you query `http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=foo`? Do you get JSONP in response (with the method name in front)?

Comment: paste in the browser http://yourserver.com/CustomerService.svc/getcustomer?method=foo i get a popup window and i save the file and open it in notepad and i see this data {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"}

Comment: @Chicagoland, there's a problem. When I run the sample project I've uploaded and navigate to the aforementioned URL I get JSONP (`foo( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"});`). Have you modified something? I really don't understand what are you doing wrong. What is clear is that until you get this exact output from your service you will never be able to call it cross domain.

Comment: @Chicagoland, I've uploaded another example this time containing a sample client (test.htm): http://www.mediafire.com/?vka4mvd9y24jifd Please follow those steps: 1. Download, 2. Extract the zip into a separate folder. 3. Double click on the `.sln` file, 4. Hit F5 to run. When `test.htm` pops up in your browser click on the test link. An alert should show the fetched user name. If this doesn't work for you I really have no idea how to help here anymore. I am beginning to suspect that you are not properly deploying your WCF service on the remote server.

Comment: it works if just f5 and run the project and i got alert('Bob') and now i am trying to put that project in dev box to test. please hang with me and i think i am closer and thank you for your help and i owe you big lunch :)

Comment: So you are not properly deploying your service on the dev box. That's an entirely different question which has nothing to do with this thread. Try something else then to confirm the cross domain: open the .htm file from the local file system like: `file:///d:/work/test.htm` in your browser. Run the web service on localhost and test. This should work. Then ask another question but this time on http://serverfault.com on how to install and configure a WCF service on a remote host with IIS as this is no longer programming related but server configuration issue.

Comment: Darin, thanks for the tips and i will try but please have a look at the error, i have uploaded here: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/3619/jsonperror.png

Comment: This error indicates that your service doesn't return JSONP in the expected format probably because it is not properly installed or you are using an OLD version.

Comment: hmm.. i have to see that now, what do you mean old version, i am using framework 3.5 and now sure what version of iis is using; when i run from 'C:\_Development\Visual Studio 2010\REST\ JSONP\WebApplication1\test.htm' i dont get alert it does not do anything what does it mean?

Comment: Did you run the web service in Visual Studio? The built-in web server needs to be running. At last use FireBug to analyze what's being sent at the wire.

Comment: hit f5 my VS service is running and open the test.htm page and i click on it and i get a alert(bob) and than i browse to the folder and double click on the test.htm file and it opens in the tab and i click on the hyperlink 'Test' and i dont get any alert and my VS is running. eghrrrrr

Comment: What does FireBug show you? Is a request sent? What does the server respond?

Comment: here is what i see in FireBug show: Parms: method jsonp1290201058580 - Response: jsonp1290201058580( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"} ); in the JSON tab is empty

Comment: so if i try like this: <a href="/service.svc/getcustomer?method=foo">Test</a> i see that firebug response: foo( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"} ); JSON tab is empty and PARMS tab have method: foo - but i dont get any alert BUT if i try with <a href="/service.svc/getcustomer?method=?">Test</a> than i see the Response: jsonp1290202395971( {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"} ); and this time i get alert message alert(Bob)

Comment: @Chicagoland, try setting an absolute `href="http://localhost:1163/service.svc/getcustomer?method=?"` on the link.

Comment: Darin: its working now if test with absoulute path in the link. so what is the next step to do to work with cross domain?

Comment: Where was the test.htm loaded from? Like `file://d:/work/test.htm`?

Comment: i test it from both loading from VS and loading from file://d:/work/test.htm both get alert message

Comment: i changed it to cross domain http://host/service.svc/getcustomer?method=? then i dont get any alert but when i look at the firebug and the response is: {"Address":"1 Example Way","Name":"Bob"}

Comment: why i am not getting alert? do you know

Comment: here is the screen shot for cross domain in firebug what data is sending: (1) http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/654/20279878.png  (2) http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/931/45417278.png

Comment: You are not getting an alert because the web service is not properly responding when calling it from this remote host. When you hosted in in Visual Studio and opened `test.htm` from windows explorer you already performed a cross domain call. What can't you understand? The web service you installed on this remote `host/service.svc` is not correct. It doesn't return the method name.

Comment: i double check the web.config on the remote server and i found that the web.config was missing custombinding section and after i correct that sure enough its working :), hey man thanks so much for your patience with me and i really appreicate your help and thanks again.

Comment: @Chicagoland, I am glad you finally managed to get this working :-) I think I've just set a new personal record in comments posting to the same question :-)

Comment: yea it was crazy journey but end up with a success.

Comment: And the morale of the story is: never give up, keep trying and learning.