# WCF data service cross domain problems jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wcf

I have created an WCF data service in a new asp.net web application and i want to call this web service from another web application using jquery, but it always returns null.

My jquery call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:2916/PennyBridge.svc/Member",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
   },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Note that "http://localhost:2916/PennyBridge.svc/Member" works in the browser but since the jquery call is from localhost:3410 i assume its a problem with cross domain.

I have been reading that i should use jsonp for this, but i have a hard time figuring it out.

What do i need to use jsonp? Do i need to configure my WCF data service?

Comment: i did a project recently , let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 3):

expose your wcf as jsonp custom binding and follow this link to fix cross domain issue.

you need to download those classes from microsoft

```
http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/
```

Comment: +1 - I wish the wcf & json story was easier, it soon will be http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-web-apis-http-your-way.aspx

Comment: @redsquare , thanks for the link , i followed the above link and some other to quickly address the problem as i don't have time..at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll check it out later when i got the time. +1

Answer (score 0):

i was in your shoe few weeks ago and here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219937/testing-building-msdn-article-json-with-padding-ajax):